# Is there a way to shorten my code?

Tags: javascript, short

I wrote this little program in javascript for practice purposes and it works perfectly fine. I'm just trying to follow the Don't Repeat Yourself rule that I learned and I'm wondering if there is any way to simplify the code I currently have (particularly the 6 if statements that check if Rattata is spelled right).

```
var spelledWrong = true

function spellRattata() {
    var letter = ["R"];
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = Math.round(Math.random());
        if(a) {
            a = "a";
            }else{
                a = "t";
                };
                letter.push(a);
    };
    if(letter[1] === "a") {
        if(letter[2] === "t") {
            if(letter[3] === "t") {
                if(letter[4] === "a") {
                    if(letter[5] === "t") {
                        if(letter[6] === "a") {
                            for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                                console.log(letter[i]);
                                };
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
};
while(spelledWrong) {
    spellRattata();
    }
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps me.

Comment: if (letter==='Rattata') will do

Comment: @barudo That will fail since `letter` is an Array. Now `letter` could be changed to a string - it isn't now.

Comment: so you need to change that to string....

Comment: This question needs to be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here, as this seems more like an opinion on refactoring and comments

Answer (score 1):

```
function spellRattata() {
  var word = "r";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    word += Math.random() > 0.5 ? "a" : "t";

  if (word == "rattata")
    return true;

  console.log(word);
  return false;
}

while (!spellRattata());
```

And if you really want to shorten it:

```
function spellRattata() {
    for (var a = "r", b = 0; b < 6; b++) a += Math.random() > .5 ? "a" : "t";
    return "rattata" == a || (console.log(a), !1)
}

for (; !spellRattata(););
```

Comment: `Math.random() >= .5` will be better

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var letter = ['R','a','t','t','a','t','a'];
letter = letter.join('');

if(letter==='Rattata')
    console.log('Correct');
else
    console.log('Wrong');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need comparing strings and buffering the letters.

- You will use the word `"attata"` on each call. So you may want to take advantage of it.
- You generate "a" for when `Math.round(Math.random())` equals to 1 otherwise you generate "t". So You actually generate "a" for each Math.random() >= 0.5. You may want to take advantage of that too
- Since we have 2 letters to determine if it matches, we may use boolean values instead of letters. TRUE for "a" and FALSE for "t"
- Using built-in functions will be better for performance when you need to manipulate arrays

Here is the snippet what shows what I want to tell above.
It works same as you need, but it is optimized for speed.

```
var ATTATA_MAP = [true, false, false, true, false, true];
var spellRattata = () => ATTATA_MAP.every(v => v === (Math.random() >= 0.5));

while(!spellRattata()) {
   console.log('wrong spelled');
}
```